# can we use twitter api to see the twetts of other company like cocacola,pepsi etc

Tags: json, api, twitter

I have web application in which it requires other company's tweet to be displayed. is it possible if i pass the username and i get the detail ? if yes where would be the best documentation to see this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the [Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/public) and the [REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public) provide various options, live streams, REST queries to specific users etc.

Comment: do you have any sample in asp.net so i would know how to use this. I tried to use this https://umerpasha.wordpress.com/2013/06/13/c-code-to-get-latest-tweets-using-twitter-api-1-1/ but didnt worked with streaming API ??

Comment: If all you want to do is embed timelines of certain users, have a look at [widgets](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines/user) and refer to the section "Override timeline selection"

Comment: This is alright but i actually want tweets data either in json array or in c# so i can loop through and show it. do you have any link where i can see this or please give me some hints.